# How do I change the active color of menu tab html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the active menu tab in navbar to be purple and inactive tab to green. link to code on fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jtsrwcu9/1/

```
        <div class="search-tab-content">
            <div class="search-bar">
                <input type="text" id="search-text" placeholder="Search Catalog" name="qu">
                <input type="image" alt="go" id="search-text-icon" title="Search" src="img.png">
            </div>
        </div>
```

I also want the placeholder in the search bar to change according to the tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this is,

I would start with a green button without the .selected class, then I would add that when it's been clicked.

This can be done in JS really easily...

If you want to use jQuery, look at this [reference page](https://api.jquery.com/click/)...
Else look at calling a function using the [onclick="function()"](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) event.

Then [add the class](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp) when it has been clicked.

**EDIT:** I've created a [JSFiddle soloution](https://jsfiddle.net/joshuacooper/15kbvhyq/31/) as requested by OP. (Excuse the JavaScript in the HTML, I'm a noob at JSfiddle XD)

```
<!-- Here is the buttons, I've gave the button I want to be selected on page first, here. That is done by giving it the selected class.-->

<button id="btn1" class="selected" onclick="click1()">First</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="click2()">Second</button>

<!-- I've put the script in the HTML because I'm a JS Fiddle Noob -->
<script>
  // The buttons are saved into a Var so it can be referenced later.
  var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
  var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

  // This what happens when clicked on the FIRST button
  function click1() {
    btn1.classList.add("selected"); // give the selected class
    btn2.classList.remove("selected"); // take away the selected class
  }

  // This what happens when clicked on the SECOND button
  function click2() {
    btn2.classList.add("selected"); // give the selected class
    btn1.classList.remove("selected"); // take away the selected class
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @Josh Cooper, don't recommend jQuery, it's [basically dead](https://hackerfall.com/story/jquery-is-dead), and is a lot of extra over-head to do something so simple. Also, don't reference w3 schools, it's over-simplified for beginners, hence doesn't follow good practices, consider MDN or Mozilla docs instead.

Comment: @Alicia, correct. jQuery can oftern bloat the page, however most people probably have it cached!

Comment: you can also use pseudo classes like :active or :visited

Comment: @NishargShah, I'm not too sure what you mean, do you mean the CSS properties like selector:hover? Because that wouldn't work. As they need to be changed regularly.